# Row dragging in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid in a WPF application, right now when I click on a cell it highlights the whole row and when I then drag down the rows it highlights all of the rows in between.

What I need is for dragging over a row to copy the value from the cell you start on over all the rows you drag it over and only highlight the rows in the specific column.

The exact words in the request were "like Excel".

Is there a written control for this? I have searched SO and have not found exactly what I am looking for. If the control does not exist, what is a good starting place?

Comment: [This post](http://blog.virtual-olympus.com/posts/2011/03/WPF-DataGrid-Drag-Drop-Behavior) looks like it may be useful.

Comment: @MikeStrobel That is very close, thank you. I need to be able to have it copy and highlight everything it moves over, but should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting place for you to learn how to code Drag and Drop.

I recently created a treeview with Drag and Drop functionality.
You might get some ideas on how drag and drop works from this project.

You can download it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bYmJ4SkEzXzdmUk0/view?usp=sharing

If you need any help then feel free to ask....

Best of Luck.....